# What is the difference of Recovery and Restore partitions?

Tags: windows-8, restore, recovery-partition

I have an Asus U38N laptop. It is UEFI enabled and has Windows 8 as operating system.
I noticed that it has both Recovery partition(900mb) and Restore Partition(20gb).
I'm cloning the operating system to smaller SSD so I would like to know if I could save few bits from deleting the Restore Partition.

So questions are:

Does anyone know difference of these Partitions?

Does other have more significance?

Answer (score 1):

The **Restore** partition - looking at it's 20GB size - would be what contains your OS recovery image data.

The **Recovery** partition - again, looking at it's relatively small size - would contain the recovery tools such as WinRE. I'm unsure why it's 900MB as opposed to the typical ~100MB.

[image]

In response to your question as a whole - regarding deleting a partition because you're migrating to a smaller SSD - I would recommend creating a recovery DVD/USB using the OS's recovery tools (that can create the DVD/USB for you) and, once you're happy the media works, you could then delete the 20GB partition.